# QLocalSocket::disconnectFromServer() doesn't disconnect socket until event loop is reentered in Qt5 in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, qlocalsocket

I compiled a program for Qt5, and now it has different run-time behavior.

In Qt5, the **socket is not disconnected until the event loop is reentered**, even though I explicitly wait for that with `waitForDisconnected()`.

For example this code:

```
socket.disconnectFromServer();
qDebug("Started waitForDisconnected...");
socket.waitForDisconnected();
qDebug("Finished waitForDisconnected.");
qDebug("Started Sleep for 10 seconds...");
Sleep(10*1000);
qDebug("Finished Sleep.");
qDebug("Started QEventLoop...");
QEventLoop().exec();
qDebug("Finished QEventLoop.");
```

Will give the following output:

```
Started waitForDisconnected...
QLocalSocket::waitForDisconnected() is not allowed in UnconnectedState
Finished waitForDisconnected.
Started Sleep for 10 seconds...
Finished Sleep.
Started QEventLoop...
```

But the socket itself is not deleted until after I get the `Started QEventLoop...` message - I know that because **I monitor this from another application** that waits for the socket to disconnect from the other side.

**When compiled with Qt4, the same code works** as it should, the socket is disconnected before `waitForDisconnected()` has returned. On Qt5 `waitForDisconnected()` returns claiming that the socket has been disconnected, when in fact it has not.

My version of Qt is 5.1.1.

Comment: actually waitForDisconnected is signaling an error as shown in `QLocalSocket::waitForDisconnected() is not allowed in UnconnectedState`

Comment: @ratchetfreak But that error is because it thinks it is already disconnected, that's why it says `not allowed in UnconnectedState`, when in fact it is still connected, the other side has not received the disconnected signal. And as I said, this doesn't happen in Qt4.

Comment: Maybe you should report this in Qt's Bug-Tracker: https://bugreports.qt-project.org
If you have done that already, maybe you could share the link here as a comment?